# Django, обновить данные поля по идентификатору

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Есть страница с информацией, со своим id,
не получается обновить данные по идентификатору

выдаёт ошибку **'str' object has no attribute 'id'**

**views.py**

```
def page(request, pk):
    item = Act.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        enter_act(self=pk)
        return redirect('main')

    return render(request, 'act_page/act_page.html', {"item": item})


def enter_act(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('UPDATE main_act SET descr=123 WHERE id = %s', [self.id])
```

Если написать *WHERE id = id* ,то все поля *descr* будут иметь значение 123, а мне нужно только то, которое редактируем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте мощь ORM

```
Act.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(descr=123)
```